# Derivative of $\frac{x+\sqrt{x}}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How does this $\frac{x+\sqrt{x}}{x^2}$ to $x^{-1} -\frac{3}{2}x^{-\frac{5}{2}}$ ?

I don't need the final answer just everything in between. I'm not sure what rules let to this.

[Here is an image, I don't know it got from line 2 to line 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7v3G.jpg)

Comment: It does not. In your first line's right expression, it must be $\;x^{-2}\;$ in the first summand for the derivative.

Comment: @Joanpemo that is what I thought straight away! but, the solution in my textbook states otherwise. Or does it just do a bad job at explaining? I have included an image of the book. Possibly errata?

Comment: Your book and my answer say exactly the same. What difference do you think there is?

Comment: @JoanpemoMy apologies, I do see that now. The way they manipulated from fractions to negative exponents in one line made me think I missed something. Which led to overthinking something simple. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{x+\sqrt x}{x^2}=\frac x{x^2}+\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2}=\frac1x+\frac1{x^{3/2}}\implies$$

$$\left(\frac1x+\frac1{x^{3/2}}\right)'=-\frac1{x^2}-\frac32\frac1{x^{5/2}}=-x^{-2}-\frac32x^{-5/2}$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{x+\sqrt{x}}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$$